# MATLAB: Make horizontal zoom default

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need Horizontal Zoom (and not the default Unconstrained Zoom) for all my figures. For a single figure, I can do this by `zoom xon` or by selecting the Zoom In button and selecting Horizontal Zoom from the right-click menu.

Is there a way to make this the default behavior (so that I need to change it everytime I create a figure)?

Answer (score 2):

If you want all new figures that open to have horizontal zoom turned on, you can set a default figure `CreateFcn` which calls `zoom xon`

```
set(0, 'DefaultFigureCreateFcn', 'zoom xon')
```

This change will be applied to all figures that you create until you reset it or restart MATLAB

```
set(0, 'DefaultFigureCreateFcn', '')
```